# can get android phone's Manufacturing Date by programmatically?

Tags: android

I'm developing app which is about showing android phone hardware and software information such as Internal storage, Screen Size, IMEI, Rooted etc. I got suck in get some information such as Manufacturing Date, Refurbished check, Phone Color, Headset connect counter, Charger connect counter and also some sensor health information such as InfraRed, Ant+, Radio Transmitter.

Is there any way to get above all things information?

Answer (score 0):

No. Sorry for the bad news, but if you could, there would alredy be an app for that.

Comment: I know and i googled lot and i found that work on Samsung devices, and that app use any Third party library which i also tried to find on google but can't get any success.
If in that app it's possible than there is some way to do get above things i want that way

Comment: Maybe some devices, like some samsung phones have such information on their hardware chips. But you will need specific commands to send to the chip... Hence the lib. But you should know that generally that is not the case

Answer (score 0):

For different informations, you have to use different methods to get.

**system service**

For example, if you want to know if know the connectivity of headset.

```
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn();
```

**build properties**

some properties can be access from `android.os.Build` directly, and all the properties can be access from the `getprop` command. The manufacture day you want to get, e.g.

```
getprop ro.build.date.utc
```

Invoking the command in you app, and parse the output of the command to get the informations you need.

```
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: got this error "Error running exec(). Command: [command] Working Directory: null Environment: null" when try to execute this line "Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command")"

Answer (score 0):

For **ScreenSize** and **Resolution**, try this code:

```
public String getScreenSizeNResolution() {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();

     getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels/dm.xdpi, 2);
    double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi, 2);
    double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
    String screenSize = String.format("%.2f", screenInches)+" inches, ";
    String screenResolution = String.valueOf(width) +"x"+ String.valueOf(height) + " pixels";
    return screenSize + screenResolution;
}
```